# Does a positive homogeneous and subadditive functional have to be nonnegative?

Tags: functional-analysis

Do positive homogeneity and subadditivtity imply nonnegativity?

Comment: Please define some of your terms or provide a link.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you are essentially talking about axioms for norms, so that positive homogeneity should mean

$$
f(\alpha x)=|\alpha| f(x). 
$$

Now note
$$
0=f(0)\leq f(x)+f(-x)=2f(x),
$$
since positive homogeneity (with $\alpha=-1$) implies $f(x)=f(-x)$. But this shows $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$.

If instead you just mean $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$ for $\alpha \geq 0$, this does not imply nonnegativity (also together with aubadditivity) as the function $f:\Bbb{R}\to \Bbb{R}, x\mapsto x$ shows.

Comment: AFAIK, positive homogenity means $f(rx)=rf(x)$ for $r\geq0$. In any case (+1)! :)